# Reproduce css3 transformation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-effects

hi is there anyone can show me ho to reproduce this css3 effect with jquery using some delay/animation speed ?

```
.element:hover{
-moz-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
-o-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
-ms-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
z-index:9999;

}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2xWXY)

Comment: isn't this just scaling the element's width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something PRETTY close to what you are asking. I'm sure you could tweak it to your liking

```
$('.element').hover(function(){

    $(this).css('position','relative').animate({
        height: $(this).height()*1.3,
        width: $(this).width()*1.3,
        left: '-=' + $(this).width() /4,
        top: '-=' + $(this).height() /4,
        'fontSize': $('.element').css('fontSize').substring(0,$('.element').css('fontSize').length -2) * 1.3 + 'px'
    },'fast');
},
 function() {                 
       $(this).css('position','relative').animate({
        height: $(this).height()/1.3,
        width: $(this).width()/1.3,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        'fontSize': $('.element').css('fontSize').substring(0,$('.element').css('fontSize').length -2) / 1.3 + 'px'
    },'fast');
}            

);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dTkhM/2/

Comment: uhmmm ... try passing many time recursively mouse over and mouse out :P

Comment: I did say it's not perfect didn't I? The problem is when you change the width and height of the div, it scales from the top left corner, and not the middle like with the css3 transform. In order to fix this I had to mess with changing the TOP and LEFT properties, but I don't know what the correct values for them should be. The other issue is that I'm not sure what CSS does with decimal values, like font-size: 13.313452px for example.

Comment: yep it wasn't offenseve my tone ;) it was just to say that your code is pretty perfect but i can't accept the answer at all cause of that little bug ;)

Comment: I understand. I'm surprised jquery doesn't have these kind of effects built in. They are all available with scriptaculous, but that's built on prototype, and not jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I might go about implementing a simple rotation (not taking frame rate into account):

```
$(function(){
    (function(n){
        this.interval = n;
        this.transform = {
            'rotation': 0
        };

        this.start = function(){
            setInterval(this.update, this.interval);
        };

        this.update = function(){
            this.transform['rotation'] = (this.transform.rotation + 10) % 360;
            $('div').css('transform', 'rotate(' + this.transform.rotation + 'deg)');
        };
        return this;
    })(30).start();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/82aUL/1/

This demonstrates a simple animation. You should be able to figure out how to put the rest of it together.

Comment: ehm .. :P ... don't know but for me that code doesn't works on jsfiddle :(

Comment: yep :p brian answer is definitive ;)

Comment: uhm found problem also on brian's :P